# Carregar Video por PHP (apenas uma parte)

Tags: php

Eu tenho alguns arquivos .MP4

Quando eu quero exibir eles, eu crio uma tav video do html e aponto para este mp4.

So que as vezes eu gostaria de transmitir apenas parte do vídeo.

Ex: o vídeo tem 10min. Mas eu quero exibir no player apenas o minuto 9 até o 10. Apôs isso o vídeo encerra.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso via PHP? Carregar via Stream apenas parte dele?

Comment: Bem, posso não ter certeza, mas creio que isso deveria ser feito no `HTML` e não no `PHP`. Nas tags `HTML5` deve ter alguma onde você indique o tempo de inicio e fim do vídeo. Mas ai não sei se teria como "esconder" a outra parte do vídeo.

Comment: Ou se existir alguma outra solução. Pois fazer isso via HTML abre brecha do usuário mexer e conseguir ver todo.

Comment: Se o usuário ver a outra parte do vídeo for problema grave, seria interessante você acrescentar isso na pergunta... Assim alguém poderá te ajudar com uma solução ainda melhor.

Answer (score 3):

Uma sugestão é gerar um novo vídeo contendo apenas o trecho que interessa.

No exemplo abaixo foi usado o [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org):

```
// Tempo em segundos
$ini = 540; // início (9 minutos)
$end = 600; // fim (10 minutos)

$original_file = '/local/arquivo/video.mp4';
$new_file = '/local/arquivo/video_short.mp4';

// Local do ffmpeg
$lib_path = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';

// Formatando o comando
$cmd = $lib_path.' -i '.$original_file.' 
-ss '.$ini.' 
-t '.$end.'
 '.$new_file;

// Executa o comando
exec($cmd);
```

Comment: Corrgi um pequeno erro de sintax, espero que não faça mal. Boa resposta

Comment: No caso, eu precisaria instalar esse ffmpeg no servidor? Tem algum exemplo?

Comment: Sim. No site oficial tem exemplos e documentação de como instalar.